# Using Fermat's Little theorem to find Fermat's last theorem question

Tags: number-theory

I have to show the first case of Fermat's Last Theorem for n=23. I was given a hint.

[*Fermat's little theorem tells us that for a prime p and an integer a that is not a multiple of p we
have a^(p-1) is one more than a multiple of p*.]
I would appreciate some guidance here because I'm stuck. In what way can I apply the hint to solve the first case?

Comment: What is the 'first case'?

Comment: @M.B. the first case is that the (prime) exponent is coprime to each number in the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Since $p=23$ is a regular prime, the result follows from Kummer's theorem. Indeed, the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{23})$ is equal to $3$, which is not divisible by $23$. Hence the equation $x^{23}+y^{23}=z^{23}$ has no integer solution with $23\nmid xyz$. The last condition is the "first case". A proof of Kummer's theorem can be found e.g., in the book L. C. Washington: Cyclotomic fields. The hint alone is not enough, I think.